# Emoji characters breaking the Apex HTTP Engine?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

When I output Emoji Characters like the ones below in Apex anywhere on the Page, the HTTP Output gets broken.

*Figure 1 - example Emojis:*

*Figure 2 - broken HTML*

[image]

With broken I mean, seemingly random character on the page disappear, and as you all may know this can lead to the whole page not being rendered correctly.

For me it seems like it's a characterset problem - maybe Apex isn't able to calculate the correct Length or something?

I am using Oracle Apex 18.1 on apex.oracle.com.

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Go to https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=51681
2. Enter 1000 into the Normal Icon Count Field and press Render
3. 1000 hearts will appear
4. Enter 1000 into the Emoji Count field and press Render
5. The HTML will break somewhere (and maybe ~1000 Emojis will appear)

The Code to output the Characters is in a dynamic PL/SQL Region and looks as following:

```
DECLARE
    l_text VARCHAR2(10) := '♥';
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1.. NVL(:P1_EMOJICOUNT_1,10) LOOP
        htp.p('<span id="myDiv'||i||'">'|| l_text ||'</span>');
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: That's weird. Not only this but it skips ~20 or so completely from v692..6-brokenone..718.

Comment: weirder simply  htp.p(i||'->'||l_text is just dandy

Comment: Yeah the behaviour is very very weird. and it doesn't matter if I output HTML in the htp.p or not. Just Emojis existing on the site break the whole HTML of the page.

Comment: If you choose a VERY high number like 100000 it will even result in a server error.

Comment: What happens if you put that piece of code into a stored procedure, and create an Apex region whose source is that PL/SQL procedure?

Comment: @Littlefoot same result - even if I put the emojis there as static text, it breaks the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently its a Problem in the PL/SQL Web Toolkit, at least thats what Joel R. Kallman, Senior Director of Software Development at Apex says.

[Quote:](https://twitter.com/joelkallman/status/1035161147740184576)

> Interesting problem.  But it seems the issue lies even beneath APEX,
>   in the PL/SQL Web Toolkit and its inability to deal with this data.

[image]

Comment: If it's related to this https://community.oracle.com/thread/4196690, I believe it's fixed in 19.2 https://tryapexnow.com/ords/f?p=2158:2

Comment: 19.2 being the database 19.2? Because apparently this wasn't an apex problem

Comment: I'm still curious as to how the problem was fixed, I just know it's fixed in the APEX 19.2 early adopter environment

Comment: tryapexnow is currently on 18.0